# React Native List View - Prepend items without rendering whole list

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement an infinite scroll with pull to refresh functionality.
I get the new data, append it via `concat` and it renders fine. The problem is that it renders the whole list with it. If i have >500 items, it becomes a nightmare.

```
onRefresh() {
    var posts = this.state.posts;
    var firstPost = posts[0].m._id;

    server.getStream('', firstPost, 4000)
        .then(res => {
             posts = res.concat(posts);
             this.setState({
                dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(posts),
                posts
             });
             this.swipeRefreshLayout && this.swipeRefreshLayout.finishRefresh();
        })

}
```

Is there a way to tell RN to render only new rows? Some sort of `key` prop maybe?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The rowHasChanged comparator in DatSource does not fire. I think that the way I've structured my component may have something to do with it.

```
renderRow(post) {

    if(post === 'loader') {
        return (
            <ProgressBarAndroid 
                styleAttr="Large" 
                style={styles.spinnerBottom}/>
        )
    }

    let hasLoader = post.m._id === lastPostId;

    let loader = hasLoader ? 
        <ProgressBarAndroid 
            styleAttr="Large" 
            style={styles.spinnerBottom}/> : null;

    return (
        <View>
            <Post 
                post={post}
                isLoadingTop={isLoadingTop}/>
            {loader}
        </View> 
    )
}

render() {

    var stream = <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                    onEndReached={this.onEndReached.bind(this)}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={1}
                    pageSize={15} />


    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Header</Text>
            </View>
            <SwipeRefreshLayoutAndroid
                ref={(c) => { 
                    this.swipeRefreshLayout = c;
                }}
                onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}>
                {stream}
            </SwipeRefreshLayoutAndroid>
        </View>
    );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `DataSource.rowHasChanged` comparator in a way that it renders `false` for rows whose data has not changed. In cases where the existing list items do not change, you can use a simple reference equality check:

```
let dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (prev, next) => prev !== next
});
```

In cases where the rows you don't want to change are not the same objects as used on the previous render pass, you need to implement a more specific comparator function.

Comment: I have .. i think: `this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({
   rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => {
    return row1 !== row2
   }
  });` I tried `console.log` inside the function, but it doesn't log anything. It's not executing for some reason.

Comment: @RadoMilushev it should work, as far as I can tell. Works in my app, just tested.

Comment: Could you update your answer with your implementation? I suspect some trivial mistake on my end but it's driving me crazy. Thank you.

Comment: The above is already literally the implementation from my codebase. However it looks like you're developing on Android, whereas my app is iOS only. Perhaps there is some issue there?